# Find harmonic function on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-functions

I have to find a harmonic function *F* on the unit disk $D_1(0)$, continuous on the closed disk $\{z | \; \vert z \vert \le 1\}$, such that for $ t\in \mathbb{R}$:

$$F(e^{it})= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{e^{(ikt)}}{k^2-3}$$

The function we find can be written as a serie, but I only understand that if $z \in \partial D_1(0)$, $$F(z)= \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{z^k}{k^2-3}$$

This function is also harmonic on $\partial D_1(0)$ but diverges inside the disk. So it is not continuous inside. I don't know where to find (maybe with Fourier series), so if you have an idea, don't hesitate!

Comment: Just to be precise: $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{k^2-3}=-\frac{1}{3}(1+\sqrt{3}\pi\cot(\sqrt{3}\pi))\simeq 1.28$

Comment: Have you covered the Poisson integral?

Comment: No, we just started the Fourier series...

Comment: Try (in polar coordinates) with: $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(k)e^{ik\theta}\rho^{|n|}$

Comment: I haven't seen Fourier transform yet...

Comment: Is is not a fourier transform, is a fourier series: $\hat{f}(n)=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{inx}f(x)dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f$ harmonic on the unit disk, such that $f_{\partial D}=F$ can be found (if $F$ satisfies certain regularity conditions, namely [Dirichlet' conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions?wprov=sfla1)) with the expression I wrote in the comments (here $\hat{F}(n)$ is the n-th fourier coefficient of $F$)

$f(\rho,\theta)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{F}(n)e^{in\theta}\rho^{|n|}$.

In fact $f$ is armonic (it is enough to do this work for a generic term in the sum, and it could be easier if you would use polar coordinates), and, since $F$ satisfies D.C., then $f(1,\theta)=F(\theta)$

From here, finding $\hat{F}$ for your specifical $F$ is easy, since it has been given already as a Fourier series.

If you are interested on some generalizations, for example working on a sphere instead that on a circumference, have a look at [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics?wprov=sfla1) and at [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: That's exactly what I found, thank you !